# How to make a batch file containing >nul on echo command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to make the batch file with this code

---

```
@echo off
echo ping -n5 localhost>nul >>hiddenping.bat
exit
```

---

the output in the hiddenping.bat is

```
ping -n5 localhost
```

> nul is not saved in the file

how to make the hiddenping.bat file containing the code
of

```
ping -n5 localhost>nul
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The caret `^` allows you to escape certain characters.

```
@echo off
echo ping -n5 localhost^>nul >>hiddenping.bat
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

I would escape the poison character(s) as foxidrive has suggested..

Another option is to put the desired string in a variable, and then ECHO the value using delayed expansion.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "str=ping -n5 localhost>nul"
echo !str!>>hiddenping.bat
```

A similar effect can be achieved via FOR variables.

```
@echo off
for %%S in ("ping -n5 localhost>nul") do echo %%S>>hiddenping.bat
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to quote the part you don't want executed now.

```
echo "ping -n5 localhost>nul" >>hiddenping.bat
```

Comment: While this will work, the quotes will end up in the `hiddenping.bat` file and may cause errors.

Comment: `'"ping -n5 localhost>nul"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`